# TypeError: insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'chars'

Tags: python, tkinter

update: i fixed the previous issue but now i have this, i have never seen this error before
TypeError: insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'chars'
if someone could explain what this means that would be great, thank you...this is the last thing i need to complete my project i have done everything else :)

```
#Imports the moduels needed
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk #EDIT: This module worked for me after I installed Pillow in my computer from "http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/installation.html"
import webbrowser #imports the module for URL links
import io, base64 #imports the module for letting images be seen without changing code

#adds the URL and window for the program tkinter
URL = "http://windowhut.com.au" #the URL used
window = tk.Tk() #this makes the tkinter window appear
window.title("window App") #title of the app
window.geometry("500x500") #size of the app

#define IntVar variables
cvar = tk.IntVar()
cvar2 = tk.IntVar()
cvar3 = tk.IntVar()

#defines the webbrowser function
def open_ph(event):
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(URL) 

#define the main button and the click button
button = tk.Button(window, text="Welcome to Awesome pizza")
button.grid(column=0, row=0)
button.bind("<Button-1>", open_ph)

#define check buttons
check1 = ttk.Checkbutton(window, text="Meat Lovers", variable=cvar, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
check1.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=(5, 95))
check2 = ttk.Checkbutton(window, text="Supreme", variable=cvar2, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
check2.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=(10, 120))
check3 = ttk.Checkbutton(window, text="Vegetarian", variable=cvar3, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
check3.grid(column=0, row=5, padx=(10, 120))

#define the option menu
choice = tk.OptionMenu(window, tk.IntVar(), "Select your size!", "Small", "Medium", "Large")
choice.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=(5, 95))

#define labels
name_label = tk.Label(text="Name")
name_label.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=(10, 120))
number_label = tk.Label(text="Contact number")
number_label.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=(5, 95))
address_label = tk.Label(text="Delivery address")
address_label.grid(column=1, row=5, padx=(5, 95))

#define entries
name_entry = tk.Entry()
name_entry.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=(5, 95))
number_entry = tk.Entry()
number_entry.grid(column=1, row=4, padx=(5, 95))
address_entry = tk.Entry()
address_entry.grid(column=1, row=6, padx=(5, 95))

#defines the print function for the message board
def message_customer():
    print(name_entry.get())
    print(number_entry.get())
    print(address_entry.get())
    name = Person(name_entry.get(), number_entry.get(), address_entry.get())                                                     
    text_answer = tk.Text(master=window, height=10, width=20)
    text_answer.grid(column=1, row=7, padx=(10, 120))
    text_answer.insert("Thank you {name} for ordering our window, it should be ready within 30 mintues!, have a great day!".format(name=name.name, number=name.number, address=name.address))

#define click button function
click_button = tk.Button(text="Complete Order", command=message_customer)
click_button.grid(column=1, row=7, padx=(5, 95))

#create class method
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, number=None, address=None):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.address = address
```

Comment: You are using `text_answer = tk.Text(name=window, height=5, width=15)` in your `message_customer` but you haven't defined it (at least in the code shown here).

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil i noticed that and changed it but now i am getting this error when i go to run the message board 
TypeError: insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'chars'
what is a "chars"?

Comment: Update your question with the new code and the new error.

Comment: just finished updating it, still getting used to this site, sorry about lack of code before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html), the `insert` method takes 2 positional (ordering matters) arguments. e.g.

```
text.insert('1.0', 'here is my text to insert')
```

You have only provided the 2nd argument, add the 1st one ("where to insert") too.

Comment: problem is i don't see what the 1st one is, i mean what part of the code would be ("where to insert")...i am really new to this and have been trying to figure it out for days

Comment: The 1st one is the position / index at which you want to "insert" the new text.

Comment: i changed it but i think i got it wrong, i got another error ><

Comment: Try reading the docs and then practically experimenting in the python interpreter / IDLE. Once you get it right there, use it in your code.

Comment: okay, thank you for the assistance you've been of great help, i appreciate your time.